# Is there any way to check for digital signature on a file programmatically in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, authenticode

I've a build script which signs a file with a digital certificate (Microsoft Authenticode). I want to create a test script which checks that the file is successfully signed. It's sufficient with a boolean indicating the existence of any signature on the file.

Can I do that with PowerShell without any extensions? If not, what do I need?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try the `Get-AuthenticodeSignature`-cmdlet

```
(Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\windows\explorer.exe").Status -eq 'Valid'

True

(Get-AuthenticodeSignature "D:\notes.txt").Status -eq 'Valid'

False
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply call [signtool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to verify the result.

Comment: SignTool counts as an extension because it's not installed by default in Windows.

Comment: My guess was that when you want to verify the signature as part of your build scripts, you'd have the build tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use sign-check util (npm required).

Install:  `npm install -g sign-check`

Usage: `sign-check 'path/to/file'`

Comment: The original question specified Powershell without any extensions.