# How can i get the publisher of a module before installation?

Tags: powershell, system-administration

I need to know if i can trust them or are all Modules from https://www.powershellgallery.com/ published by microsoft ?

I saw powershellget(module) on https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/powershellget/?view=powershellget-3.x but also on psgallary but everyone can publish there. But i need to know for work , if we install other modules .

I know if u install a module u get a prompt with this information (if untrusted) , but why can i just read it in the web or a hash key for verification ?

Thanks for help.

I am german , sry for my english <3

Comment: You can see the author of packages on the gallery before downloading by using `Find-Module`.  For example: `Find-Module -Name 'WindowsDefender' | Format-Table, Name Version, Author`.  Official Microsoft modules, for example, have `Microsoft Corporation` listed as the author.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing necessary to publish code to `PS Gallery` is an Azure Account. And that in it self doesn't guarantee the id of the publisher.

What you are looking for is signed code, which isn't a requirement for uploading code to `PS Gallery`.

The signature of the code will be inspected automatically by PowerShell before execution.

After you've installed a module or a script from `PS Gallery`, you can verify that the signature is valid by hand (if one is present) using

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath "C:\Test\NewScript.ps1"
```

Ref:

- [MS Learn - Get-AuthenticodeSignature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-authenticodesignature?view=powershell-5.1&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp)
- [MS Learn - Introduction to Code Signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537361(v=vs.85))
- [MS Learn - about_Signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_signing)
- [MS Learn - Code-Signing Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn653556(v=vs.85))
- [SO - Is there any way to check for digital signature on a file programmatically in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876589/is-there-any-way-to-check-for-digital-signature-on-a-file-programmatically-in-po)

Comment: You can also use `Save-Module` to download it without installing it in a module folder - allows you to inspect the code and validate the signature before ever attempting to import it